# Does Oracle use rowid to recover from redo log and archives?

Tags: oracle, rman

I am learning about supplemental logging and this questios has came into my mind. What I have understood is, Oracle just save an image of the modified column in redo logs, that is why we need to enable supplemental logging to use log miner or golden gate for example, then we will have sufficient information to reconstruct the modified rows using sql apply. But when Oracle does not have any supplemental logging enabled, how oracle recover this images during a recover situation, I mean, for example `recover database` from RMAN, is it by rowid?

Answer (score 1):

From [*Oracle Database Utilities*](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-D857AF96-AC24-4CA1-B620-8EA3DF30D72E.htm#SUTIL1582) - section Supplemental Logging

> An application that applies reconstructed SQL statements to a
> different database must identify the update statement by a set of
> columns that uniquely identify the row (for example, a primary key),
> not by the ROWID shown in the reconstructed SQL returned by the
> V$LOGMNR_CONTENTS view, because the ROWID of one database will be
> different and therefore meaningless in another database

While they don't say it in so many words, the "not by ROWID" (in the context of the sentence) strongly suggests that normal redo recovery *is* by rowid..